# Can you set an array in mailjet

Tags: mailjet

I know that you can do

```
{% set yo-yo = "Benjamin" %}
```

or

```
{% set yo-yo = 1 %}
```

in mailjet. My question is if you can do something like:

```
{% set a = [1, 2, 3] %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for now not. You could only set your var to be equals a simple value, not an array or an object.

On the other hand, you could set your custom variables to be an array which you could later on loop through.

Here that could come in handy => https://dev.mailjet.com/template-language/